# Cannot input to textfield of inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have created a input accessory view, the code is below:

```
import UIKit

class ChatInputView: UIView {
    let textView: ChatTextView = {
        let textView = ChatTextView()
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        textView.keyboardType = .Default
        textView.returnKeyType = .Send
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15.0)

        return textView
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        addSubview(textView)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "textViewNeedsUpdateDisplay", name: UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "textViewNeedsUpdateDisplay", name: UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "textViewNeedsUpdateDisplay", name: UITextViewTextDidEndEditingNotification, object: nil)

        textView.positionToSuperView(horizontal: UIView.Horizontal.Left, hOffset: 15.0, vertical: UIView.Vertical.Top, vOffset: 15.0)
        textView.positionToSuperView(horizontal: UIView.Horizontal.Right, hOffset: 15.0, vertical: UIView.Vertical.Bottom, vOffset: 15.0)
    }

    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
        let height = textView.intrinsicContentSize().height + 30.0 > UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height / 3.0 ? UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height / 3.0 : textView.intrinsicContentSize().height + 30.0
        let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width

        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }

    func textViewNeedsUpdateDisplay() {
        textView.setNeedsDisplay()
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }

}

class ChatTextView: UITextView {
    override var text: String! {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect)

        if text.characters.count == 0 {
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingTail
            paragraphStyle.alignment = .Left

            let placeholderTextAttributes: [String: AnyObject] = [
                NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15.0),
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGrayColor(),
                NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle
            ]

            (NSLocalizedString("输入一些字来回复...", comment: "") as NSString).drawInRect(CGRectInset(rect, 7, 8), withAttributes: placeholderTextAttributes)
        }
    }

    override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
        return sizeThatFits(CGSize())
    }

}
```

and used it as follow

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView! {
    get {
        return ChatInputView()
    }
}
```

But when I click on the text field, the keyboard can show, but cannot input to the textfield.Tried my methods but still cannot get it to work.

Anyone can tell me the reason.

Comment: Do you need to override [`canBecomeFirstResponder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/canBecomeFirstResponder) and return true, perhaps?

Comment: Tried, but not work.Really confused me very much, I checked implementation on Github, I think it is the same implementation, but just not work on mine.